# DRF - created_by and last_updated_by fields - how to make it work?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, request

How to make `created_by` and `last_updated_by` fields work in `Django REST Framework`?
Created by should be populated when the object is created and `last_updated_by` should be updated any time the object is updated.

The usual way is to use `CurrentUserDefault` but that is not working on PATCH methods if the `last_updated_by` is not included in the payload.

```
last_updated_by = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

Do you know how to do that? Maybe the best way would be to modify the `serializer` data inside the `ViewSet` but I can't figure out how.

EDIT product model

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    objects = ProductManager()

    created_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='products', null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name='Created by')

    last_updated_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='products_updated', null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name='Updated by')
```

Comment: This can be done in your model. why you need DRF

Comment: My whole project is based on DRF. How can I do that in the model? By passing optional argument `request` to save method?

Comment: Show your any model @Milano

Comment: @c.grey I've added an interesting part of the model to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the created_by, updated_by logic in the viewset
Like this

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(created_by=user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(last_updated_by=user)
```